# Recording only AUDIO using AVCaptureSession

Tags: objective-c, audio, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

I would like to record audio using AVCaptureSession, and Audio only (without video). I followed RosyWriter sample (removing all code concerning video), but when I create my AsseWriter for audio I have an error with hte line :

```
assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:captureURL fileType:(NSString*)kUTTypeAUdio error:&error];
```

the error is : *Invalide file type UTI...*

captureURL is as following :

```
NSURL captureURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"captureTest.mp3"]];
```

Do you know how to fix it ? I tried with kUTTypeMP3 or kUTTypeMPEG4Audio but nothing change.

I try to use only audio, because I need to do a AVCaptureSession and separate audio from video to send them separatly to a server.

I'm interested in any sample of code that can help me.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

`kUTTypeAudio` is too vague - try something like `AVFileTypeWAVE` or `AVFileTypeAppleM4A`.

p.s. iOS doesn't have an mp3 encoder (it does have a decoder)